# How many S3 buckets(CloudFront Distribution) for the best logging (charging)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I know that there are plenty of services and tools to read logs.

Here is the problem :

If I'm planning to charge my users by their usage, then should I create buckets for all of them or can I create folders for all of them and log something like folder bandwidth or usage?

I also want to use cloudfront distribution. If I create buckets for all of my users, then how can I manage cloudfront distribution too? (all distributions are associated with a specific bucket?)

I want to hear your suggestions.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Each AWS account can only have a maximum of 100 buckets so unless you plan on having less than 100 users, you'll need to use folders within buckets.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: Thanks. So, it's impossible to scale bw of each user(if they are more than 100) by not using any other server to handle requests?

Comment: I dont follow what you mean? You're not going to have any scaling issues but you're going to have to build in bandwidth monitoring and usage at the application layer and/or have other tasks to parse log files and get folder sizes etc.

Comment: Here is the scenario: A user will upload his file. I will put them into s3bucket. Every user will have a unique folder. Their files will be kept under those unique folders. When a user ask for his files, lets say video url to stream, I will give him directly cloudfront link. Now, my aim is to monitor bandwidth. Here, every user will be available to share his files' links. I want to know how much their files used seperately? The issue is scaling "folder bandwidth"

Comment: Scaling is not an issue. You can have as many files/folders in a bucket as you like. But to monitor bandwidth, you have to parse the Cloudfront and S3 log files yourself to determine a particular users usage.

Answer (score 1):

> planning to charge my users by their usage

I think you can use Bucket Tagging which can also help to AWS Cost Allocation For Customer Bills.

[About Bucket Tagging](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/08/aws-cost-allocation.html)